# Disable background hover effects when a fancy-box popup is open

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I'm using fancy-box for my image gallery.images in my gallery are angled using css and it looks like a card pack.when a user hover on a image the image rotates and it looks flat(rotate to 0 degree).when a user click on a image the fancy fox popup will appear.here is my code for that.

```
.book:hover {

   -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
   -moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
   -ms-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
   -o-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
   transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
   box-shadow: none;
   z-index: 5;
  }
.book {

 -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(22deg) scale(0.9);
 -moz-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(22deg) scale(0.9);
 -ms-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(22deg) scale(0.9);
 -o-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(22deg) scale(0.9);
 transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(22deg) scale(0.9);

 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;

}
```

Initializing fancy-box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.inline").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        openSpeed: 300,
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        closeSpeed: 300,
        scrolling : 'no',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)',

                },
            } 
        }, 
    });
});
```

all working fine up to now.problem comes when a fancy-box popup is opened and the close icon on the popup box is placed on top of a image. i have attached a picture of this issue:

[image]

in this situation when i try to click the close button on fancy-box the fancy-box is not closing and the background image hover effect is working.So i want to disable that hover effects on images when a fancy box popup is open.how to do that?

Comment: In a normal scenario, the fancybox overlay (dimmed) blocks the page behind so not any hover effect should take place, demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ek6dE/ I guess there is an issue with your css declarations. What browser/OS reproduces that behavior?

Comment: This problem happens in google chrome. firefox works fine